# Take appropriate action after confirmation dialog is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a confirmation dialog made with jQuery UI.
I'm trying to take appropriate action after the users reaction (whether `yes` or `no`):

```
$("button").click(function() {
  if (showDialog('Do you want to continue?')) {
    console.log("yes");
  } else {
    console.log("no");
  }
});

function showDialog(message) {
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        dfd.resolve();
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "No": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  $("#dialog").html(message);
}
```

In my case, I always get a `no`.

Also, the `no` appears even before a button is clicked. So I assume, this is asynchronous. Is there a way to prevent that, too?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj66nbgu/1/).

Comment: Why are you using `$.Deferred()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path with the deferred, but you weren't actually listening for it to resolve or reject:

```
      $("button").click(function() {
            showDialog('Do you want to continue?').then(function() {
                console.log("yes");
            }, function() {
                console.log("no");
            })
        });

        function showDialog(message) {
            var dfd = new $.Deferred();
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function() {
                        dfd.resolve();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "No": function() {
                        dfd.reject();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog").html(message);
            return dfd;
        }
```

Here is your fiddle updated to work https://jsfiddle.net/v86bc028/1/

Edit - second fiddle showing resolve used for both buttons
https://jsfiddle.net/35edpgxp/1/

Comment: Is there any way to to specify some code, that needs to be executed, independent of the clicked button?

Comment: You dont have to use resolve and reject. You could call resolve in both cases and pass some information to it. Then access that information in the success handler function (the first function passed into then()).

Comment: I added another fiddle to my answer showing how you would do that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$.Deferred`. Also, the logic that would happen when the user press the Yes or No button should be in the functions provided in the "buttons" config option. Like this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  showDialog('Do you want to continue?');
});

function showDialog(message) {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
       console.log('yes');
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "No": function() {
        console.log('no');
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  $("#dialog").html(message);
}
```